# How to avoid 'CharMap' codec error when creating BertLMDataBunch object for French texts

Tags: nlp, bert-language-model, charmap

## Issues with BertLMDataBunch.from_raw_corpus(), 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u0627' in position 0: character maps to

[bertlmdatabunch](/questions/tagged/bertlmdatabunch)

When creating a **BertLMDataBunch** object, I got issue that 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u0627' in position 0.
When I tried to encode my texts using utf-8, I got this error : 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 20-25: character maps to
I also thought about avoiding punctuation or special characters like 'éèêçàôûù' but I got the same error.

**df_train** is my labeled dataset, and **Description** is the column with french texts.

```
DATA_PATH = Path('./data/')

all_texts = df_train['Description'].to_list()
all_texts = [ (x.encode('utf-8', errors='ignore')).decode('utf-8', errors='ignore') for x in all_texts]
```

The texts also contain numbers

[the BertLMDataBunch object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/alskB.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDq8h.png)

The object I created generates a text file **lm_trained** that contains texts like this :

`Bonjour Le 21 Avril 2021 j ai envoy� une r�clamation`

If anyone can help me to fix this. Thank you !

Comment: Please revise your question to include a minimal reproducible example that can demonstrate the bug. Present it as text, not screenshots. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)